# Rails overriding Mini-Test templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I am trying to override the generator templates [here](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/mini_test), but am having no luck.
I have configured mini-test to use the spec syntax, and it generates the spec template but not my custom one. Also it calls the generated file for example *controller_test.rb even though it contains the spec syntax.

Here is my structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it turns out that the mini-test folder should be mini_test